# Can anyone explain the logic regarding creation of ArrayList

Tags: java

I was writing the solution for permutation for array on leetcode. This was the code I wrote.

```
class Solution {
    List<List<Integer>> lists = new ArrayList<>();
    public List<List<Integer>> subsets(int[] nums) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        permutation(list,nums,0);
        
        return lists;
    }
    
    void permutation(List<Integer> list,int[] nums,int curr)
    {
        
        if(curr == nums.length)
        {
            lists.add(list);
            return;
        }
        
        list.add(nums[curr]);
        permutation(list,nums,curr+1);
        list.remove(list.size() - 1);
        permutation(list,nums,curr+1);
        
    }
}
```

But with this I was getting wrong output:
Wrong Answer
Runtime: 0 ms
Your input
[1,2,3]
Output
[[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
Expected
[[],[1],[2],[1,2],[3],[1,3],[2,3],[1,2,3]]

So I searched for the error and I found making slight change will make it correct :
lists.add(list) -> lists.add(new ArrayList(list))

```
class Solution {
    List<List<Integer>> lists = new ArrayList<>();
    public List<List<Integer>> subsets(int[] nums) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        permutation(list,nums,0);
        
        return lists;
    }
    
    void permutation(List<Integer> list,int[] nums,int curr)
    {
        
        if(curr == nums.length)
        {
            lists.add(new ArrayList(list));
            return;
        }
        
        list.add(nums[curr]);
        permutation(list,nums,curr+1);
        list.remove(list.size() - 1);
        permutation(list,nums,curr+1);
        
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain the logic behind this?

Comment: What was the search result you got? Can you link to it? Surely that page explained the solution?

Comment: You can debug and see that the same "list" is changed all along your function stack and the changes reflect in all your output lists. When the recursion ends your list is empty that empty list is reflected in all elements of the output and hence you see that output.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code adds the reference list.  list is modified and eventually become empty.  so, lists will have a list of empty lists.

```
lists.add(list);
```

This line of code adds a copy of list.  Since modification is done to the original list, it doesn't affect the copy.

```
lists.add(new ArrayList(list));
```